How to prevent DaisyUI Buttons from expanding to full width when using them in a flexbox?
 <div className="flex flex-col p-3">
    <div className="flex flex-col  mb-4">
        <button className="btn btn-link btn-sm">Statistik anzeigen</button>
        <button className="btn btn-link btn-sm">Schadenskategorien hinzufügen</button>
        <button className="btn btn-link btn-sm">CSV der aktuellen Auswahl exportieren</button>
    </div>
 </div>

The buttons in the in the div take up the whole screen width. I cant get them to shrink to their content width
I tried applying the tailwind class w-auto and flex-shrink-0. But that didnt help

You could consider applying align-items: center to the flex layout container via the items-center class. This overrides the default align-items: stretch that is causing the buttons to extend the whole width of the container.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@4.12.14/dist/full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.15"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col p-3">
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center mb-4">
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Statistik anzeigen</button>
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Schadenskategorien hinzufügen</button>
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm">CSV der aktuellen Auswahl exportieren</button>
  </div>
 </div>



